# Driving WS2812 using DMA on STM32F302

Tags: led, stm32

I'm trying to drive some WS2812 LEDs which require a (400ns high + 800ns low) or (800ns high + 400ns low) signal to indicate a 0 or a 1.

So essentially I'm trying to take an array of data and output it directly to a GPIO at about 2.5MHz. I've never used the DMA before but from what I understand it should be able to output data straight from memory to a GPIO.

Can anyone offer some guidance on how to setup the DMA to do this, or if there are any better ways of outputting data on a GPIO at a consistent clock?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a UART, SPI or I2S interface, using one byte to generate the waveform for one bit. The important point is that such interfaces have a FIFO buffer, so the CPU's activities don't need to be exactly synchronous with the output signal.

A student of me did this succesfully on a LPC1114.

Maybe you can use DMA to feed the serial interface, but you'd have to 'blow up' the data to one byte per bit.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet confirms that toggling GPIO is possible at 2.5 MHz

> Fast I/O handling allows I/O toggling up to 36 MHz

DMA writes to GPIO is possible (Looking at the DMA section block diagram). If you could write to GPIO directly to GPIO_data registers.

DMA cannot be used because of your constraint in Duty Cycle for logic low and logic high. I would suggest to try coding in C, driving the GPIOs directly (switch to asm or inline,if supported by toolchain) if speed of 1/400 ns = 2.5 MHz is required and extra time in between.
Edit: 
In order to use DMA, as per the comment below so that the processor can be free, the duty cycle is still 66.66% and 33.33% as per the requirement in OP. But only thing is that the rate will increase to 2.5 MHz. I am yet to explore DMA configuration to check the possibility.
[image]

Comment: Eh, DC isn't a problem unless there are delays or returns to zero between bytes. Since the signal is fairly regular you can use 3 output bits per WS281X bit in the signal (100 for 0, 110 for 1).

Comment: It won't increase to 7.5MHz; the base signal is 800kHz, so 2.5MHz is approximately correct.

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea of generating the PWM with digital signals. I have corrected it to 2.5 MHz and continuing with configuration

Answer (score 0):

1.With a STM32, set the Clock Speed @ 40/80/120 MHz and use the SPI with output to MOSI. Use SPI and DMA channel. The pulse will be at 400us. At 80Mhz, SPI divider will be 32.

2. Setup the SPI like that:

   hdma_spi1_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;

   hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;

3.Setup the DMA port like that:

DMA1_Channel3->CPAR  = (uint32_t)&(SPI1->DR);

DMA1_Channel3->CMAR  = (uint32_t)pixels; // to send to ws2812

DMA1_Channel3->CCR  |= DMA_CCR_DIR |  DMA_CCR_MINC;

NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn, 0);

NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn);

4.Encode the data correctly before sending. Bit 1 will be 110 and Bit 0: 100. So, if you have 10 leds WS2812 x 3 bytes (24 bits) x 3 pulses = 90 bytes

5. Leave the first and last byte of stream to send to WS2812 blank (0). The first byte will be use to reset the strip.

6.Send data to the WS2812 with the DMA
    HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA( &hspi1, pixels,  numBytes );

7.Wait 1.25ms x leds before sending again